# I need the text of a transaction field to act as a variable in a NetSuite saved search that is being built via a portlet

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am adding a custom list portlet in my customer center environment that uses a custom field that holds a value that represents the internal IDs of all the items a customer has bought. This value will be used as a filter in a saved search whose data will populate the list portlet.

The text of the field looks like "123","456" etc.

I can successfully retrieve the field text per my debugger, but when I go to pass the value of the field as a variable to my filters it produces an error message:

```
Filter expecting numeric value was removed, as non-numeric value ... was provided.
```

Using the NetSuite search export to recreate what I am looking for non-dynamically produces the below code:

```
var customrecord_vcc_documentsSearchObj = search.create({
   type: "customrecord_vcc_documents",
   filters:
   [
     [["custrecord_vcc_customer_docs","anyof","@CURRENT@"],"AND",["custrecord_vcc_doc_type","noneof","1"]],
      "OR", 
      ["custrecord_vcc_doc_type","anyof","5"],
      "OR", 
      [["custrecord_vcc_doc_type","anyof","2","3","4","6","7"],"AND",["custrecord_vcc_doc_item","anyof","2291","3546","2279","1976"]]
   ],
   columns:
   [
      search.createColumn({
         name: "name",
         sort: search.Sort.ASC,
         label: "Name"
      }),
      search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_vcc_doc_type", label: "Type"}),
      search.createColumn({
         name: "formulatext",
         formula: "'<a href='||{custrecord_vcc_link_to_file}||'>Open</a>'",
         label: "Link"
      })
   ]
});
```

When I try to replace:

```
["custrecord_vcc_doc_item","anyof","2291","3546","2279","1976"]
```

In order to replace the fixed IDs I used the below code:

```
var transactionSearchObj = search.create({
   type: "transaction",
   filters:
   [
      ["name","anyof","@CURRENT@"]
   ],
   columns:
   [
      search.createColumn({
         name: "custbody_vcc_item_array_fixed",
         summary: "MAX",
         label: "Item Array Fixed"
      })
   ]
});

var itemarray=[];

transactionSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
    var itemarray1 = result.getValue({
        name: "custbody_vcc_item_array_fixed",
        summary: search.Summary.MAX
    });
    itemarray.push(itemarray1);
    log.debug({
        title: "Items",
        details: itemarray1
    });
    //return true;
});

var itemarraytext = itemarray.toString();

log.debug({
    title: "Item Array String",
    details: itemarraytext
});

log.debug({
    title: "Item Array ",
    details: itemarray
});
```

and input itemarraytext in the place of the fixed IDs. The value of itemarraytext per my debugger is:

```
"2191","2046","1209","1209","1988","2092","295","1214","1988",...
```

but the error message persists and the filter is not applied.

This is running in NetSuite's customer center, so I can't access the customer record because the customer center role does not have access to the customer list. I also can't access item internal ids directly via saved searches using {item.internalid} for the same reasons re: permissioning.

The work around is a dynamic field that sets a static field that I am searching on via a transaction search, the static field text should be the text of the filter.

Ideally speaking, the variable itemarraytext would pass through and filter the available documents I am searching for based on each customer's purchase history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are building an array of strings of comma separated items:

```
[
    '"2191","2046","1209"',
    '"1209","1988","2092"',
    '"295","1214","1988"'
]
```

and then calling the toString method to create:

```
'"2191","2046","1209","1209","1988","2092","295","1214","1988"'
```

and passing that string to your search filter:

```
["custrecord_vcc_doc_item","anyof",'"2191","2046","1209","1209","1988","2092","295","1214","1988"']
```

and the filter does not recognize `'"2191","2046","1209","1209","1988","2092","295","1214","1988"'` as a number.

Instead, you need to replace the double quotes and split your itemarraytext variable at the comma:

```
["custrecord_vcc_doc_item","anyof",itemarraytext.replace(/"/g,'').split(',')];
```

which should be the equivalent of:

```
["custrecord_vcc_doc_item","anyof",["2191","2046","1209","1209","1988","2092","295","1214","1988"]]
```

Comment: I can't get an array of the item ids because the customer center role can't access to the item record. The result is a permissioning error. The work around I came up with was to store the ids in a field to try and recreate the text input that the NetSuite search export extension spit out, which I then push to my array and run through the .toString() method to try and recreate the text inputs.

When I run the script with just the array variable, itemarray, I get the same errors:

Error Search filter removed Filter expecting numeric value was removed, as non-numeric value '2191","2046",...

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm. Its still creating some errors, but the end result is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: This ended up not working in later testing, but I ended up finding a simpler solution that was right in front of my eyes. The reason I couldn't get to the item ids as a regular array through search was a permissioning issue, so I changed the script deployment to run as an admin role as opposed to the "current role". This allowed me to access the item IDs I needed and pass it through as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Circling back to post a different solution I ended up using in the end.

I was able to work around the permissioning error by changing the script deployment "Run As" role field from current role to "Administrator". This allowed me to simply access the item IDs from a search and pass them through as an array to another filter.

The final code ended up being:

```
var transactionSearchObj = search.create({
   type: "transaction",
   filters:
   [
      ["name","anyof","@CURRENT@"], 
      "AND", 
      ["item.type","anyof","InvtPart"]
   ],
   columns:
   [
      search.createColumn({
         name: "item",
         sort: search.Sort.ASC,
          summary: "GROUP",
         label: "Item"
      })
   ]
});




transactionSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
    var itemarray1 = result.getValue({
        summary: "GROUP",
        name: "item"
    })
    itemarray.push(itemarray1);
    log.debug({
        title: "Items",
        details: itemarray1
    });
    return true;
});





log.debug({
    title: "Item Array",
    details: itemarray
});







 var customrecord_vcc_documentsSearchObj = search.create({
   type: "customrecord_vcc_documents",
   filters:
   [
     [["custrecord_vcc_customer_docs","anyof","@CURRENT@"],"AND",["custrecord_vcc_doc_type","noneof","1"]],
      "OR", 
      ["custrecord_vcc_doc_type","anyof","5"],
      "OR", 
      [["custrecord_vcc_doc_type","anyof","2","3","4","6","7"],"AND",["custrecord_vcc_doc_item","anyof",itemarray]]
   ],
```